# Animate multiple lines in multiple plots using animation

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7

I'm trying to animate N particles that interact with eachother under the influence of the coulomb force. I made a function which recursively creates each x and y position of each particle, as well as the potential energy, and adds them to a list. Using animation from matplotlib, I tried to animate x,y in one subplot, and the energy in another. However, when I try to animate both, it only manages to animate a single subplot. 
I'm pretty new to python but I struggle to find any information about animating multiple lines in each subplot.

I have tried to only use one animation() and init() function, but that only worked if I used a single particle. I cannot do this with multiple particles (to my knowledge), so I made two animation() functions and two init() functions.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)

ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax1.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 0.0001)

lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)] 
lines2 = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)]
```

I have a function which adds x,y and Epot to a list which contains lists for all particles.

```
def init():
    for line1 in lines:
        line1.set_data([], [])
    return lines

def init2():
    for line2 in lines2:
        line2.set_data([], [])
    return lines2

def animate(i):
    for J,line1 in enumerate(lines):
        function(i,J,N) 
        line1.set_data(tijd[J], Epot[J])
    return lines

def animate2(i):
    for J,line2 in enumerate(lines2):
        function(i,J,N)
        line2.set_data(x[J], y[J])
    return lines2
```

Finally, at the end of the code I have:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1000, interval=20, repeat=False, blit=False)
anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, init_func=init2, frames=1000, interval=20, repeat=False, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

But whenever I execute this, it only animates anim2. I know I'm missing something but I can't find the right solution.

Comment: You need *one* init function, *one* animate function and *one*  FuncAnimation.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thank you. I did try something in the sense of adding the two together like ```lines = lines1+lines2``` and then returning that from one init function, but that didn't seem to work. I'll try to investigate further.

Comment: Yes that should work. If it doesn't I would suggest to update the code in the question with the actual problem you face now.